# Firestore query using an object element as parameter

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

i'm using Firestore as my database in a project and i have a table that i need to do a query inside an object

```
{
   foo: "data",
   bar: "data",
   exObject: {
      dataToQuery: "value"
   }
}
```

here is an example of a structure where i want to do a query inside the object
a query that would look like this:

```
dbRef.collection("Table").where("exObject.dataToQuery", "==", "value")
```

but this is not working.

Is there a way to query in Firestore using an object's inner value as parameter?
If not, is there a way to achieve something that would give the same result?

Example of a Firestore Structure

[image]

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
dbRef.collection("Table").where("exObject.dataToQuery", "==", "value")
```

this syntax i first posted is indeed the good syntax and started working eventually. I'd class the reason of my problem as a typo that i must have corrected trying a lot of different things

Comment: I realize this is a year old, but I'm working with the same .where method on firestore. I just don't know how to access the data returned. the Object returned shows the right id under the QuerySnapshot, but I don't see the actual object itself.  How did you access the object it returns?

Comment: `let theResults = dbRef.collection("Table").where("exObject.dataToQuery", "==", "value")`

Answer (score 6):

Here is the answer :

```
.where(new firestore.FieldPath('exObject' , 'dataToQuery'), '==', "value"))
```

More info [Here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.FieldPath)

Comment: Not the OP here, but thank you for sharing this. I think FieldPath is useful and yet underused.

Answer (score 0):

Try **( change from 'Table' to 'TEST' )**

```
xptoCollection : AngularFirestoreCollection<any>;

  constructor(private afs: AngularFirestore) { }

      this.xptoCollection = this.afs.collection('TEST', ref => {
        return ref.where('exObject.{dataToQuery}', '==', 'value');
      });
```

Comment: doesn't seem to do the trick, the query still returns 0 result

Answer (score -5):

for some reason to work ,
u need to leave space between object_name and .property_name

```
'exObject .dataToQuery'
```

instead of

```
 'exObject.dataToQuery'
```

leave space and it worked for me